# 100% expandable container div with outside margin

Tags: css, height, width, margin

i have a mind bobbling question.

I need a 100% width, 100% height container with 20px margin that expands with content. Is this at all possible? The closest i got was with this method:

```
#container {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:20px;
}
```

but then it wont expand in height with content.

Anybody know the divine technique for this?

Comment: I can't quite envision what you're asking for. Can you explain more?

Comment: Yes. I need a div, which is 100% in height and 100% in width, but width 20px of space all around. Like this: http://manual.businesstool.dk/screen.jpg
Let me know, if that didnt help? :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it isn't possible to do with a single element, but if you don't mind having 3 spacer `div` elements, this solution works in all browsers:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%; padding: 0; /* padding 0 is for jsfiddle */
}
#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: -20px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the spacer height */
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.spacer.edge {
    background-color: white; /* same as body background */ 
}
.spacer {
    height: 20px;
 }

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="spacer edge"></div>
        <!-- content here -->
        <div class="spacer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer edge"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a fiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/dTyTW/

Comment: Your original solution (http://jsfiddle.net/dTyTW/) works in even IE6, but your updated one fails in all browsers when there is little content. You should revert back to your original solution, I think it's exactly what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @thirydot heh I only tested the updated one in chrome. Reverted to previous. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: This works like a charm! Very creative work around ;) Thumbs up for no js, and it works in all browsers. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `margin` and give each position a `20px`.

Also remove the `bottom`.

Add `padding-bottom:20px;`

```
#container {
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
    right:20px;
    padding-bottom:20px; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/w7dQP/3/

**EDIT**

If you are not opposed to using some jQuery, you could also do this

```
var h = $(document).height();
var h2 = $('#container').height();

if(h2 < h){
    $('#container').height(h);
}
```

This ensures that if the `div` is smaller than the browser viewport, it will expand to fit it.

Once the text is as big or bigger, the styles will take care of it.

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/w7dQP/8/

Comment: You're right, @Esben.  This only works if the content is already 100% or more of the height of the screen.

Comment: See my edit above for if the content is smaller than 100% of the screen height.

Comment: Heh i actually did fix it temporary with jQuery, but it bumps me out, that i cant do it in pure css, which is why i started this thread.

Answer (score 0):

I you want to expand the div with the content , then you need to set position : relative and in order to stick towards the bottom padding-bottom also need to be set.

```
#container {
position:relative;
top:20px;
bottom:20px;
left:20px;
right:20px;
padding-bottom: 80%;
border:1px solid red;
```

}

Values can be adjusted as per the requirement.
Try [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/w7dQP/)

Comment: This does not work neither, it expands beyond the window, even if its empty. Which is not the intent :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<style>
body
{
  margin:0px;
}
div
{
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px;
}
img
{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
<body>
  <div>
    <img src="http://manual.businesstool.dk/screen.jpg" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Use the padding property... look up the box model.